# SQL how to tie tables together

Tags: sql, join, select

My professor said I did not tie between tables, now I want to ask how to tie tables, this are two of my example I did incorrect.

Query2 - no ties between tables

```
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, [Order Details].UnitPrice
FROM Customers, [Order Details]
WHERE ((([Order Details].UnitPrice)>=50));
```

Query3 - no ties between tables

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ShippedDate
FROM Products, Orders
where Orders.ShippedDate between ('1996-07-01') and ('1996-07-31')
ORDER BY Orders.ShippedDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your query is missing a join conditions between the two tables. Without it, you get a cartesian products of the rows from both tables.

This is where the `join` syntax comes into play. For example for the second query, assuming that `products` and `orders` relate through column `product_id`:

```
select p.productid, p.productname, o.shippeddate
from products p
inner join orders o on o.product_id = p.product_id
where o.shippeddate >= '1996-07-01' and o.shippeddate < '1996-08-01'
order by o.shippeddate;
```

Other improvements to the query:

- table aliases make the query easier to write and read
- half-open intervals for date comparisons are handy: they properly handle the time portion of the dates (if any)